# How to disable hostname verification in WSO2 Api Manager?

Tags: apache-axis, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

how can I disable hostname verification on WSO2 Api Manager 2.5?

I'm getting the following error, having WSO2-AM and WSO2-EI 6.3 deployed on two different docker containers:

[2018-11-15 11:31:06,194]  WARN - login:jag Not Retrieving Pending Tasks. Check BPS Connectivity. javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <100.64.45.16> != <localhost>

I tried all the possible configurations described here, but they don't disable it:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Enabling+HostName+Verification#EnablingHostNameVerification-hostname_verification_newConfiguringhostnameverification(Carbon4.4.17onwards)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have the following property in wso2server.sh in wso2am-2.5.0?
-Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier="AllowAll"

Comment: @Pubci yes, I added it but it doesn't work

Comment: @Pubci I also tried the following 2 configurations without success:
 - add `<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>` into the axis2.xml 
 - add the following in synapse.properties:
     `keystore.trust.location=repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
     keystore.trust.type=JKS 
     keystore.trust.alias=wso2carbon
     keystore.trust.store.password=wso2carbon
     keystore.trust.parameters=enableHostnameVerifier=false`

Comment: I usually create a custom certificate (like  `*.wso2.local`) and then refer the docker nodes  with the hostnames. As well you can use http transport (no ssl) between the docker containers